# GDB (on windows+mingw64, compiled) Error: Process record: the current architecture doesn't support record function

Tags: gdb

I'm pretty new to GDB, so anyways when I try to do the record command, I get the "Process record: the current architecture doesn't support record function." error.
How do I fix it?
I'm on windows 10, with an AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Vega Mobile GFX CPU and an AMD Radeon RX 560X Series GPU

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZSM6.png)

I expected it to start "recording" and so then I could reverse continue the program or step back.

Comment: It's just as it says, the record functionality does not work on Windows.